# Where does Prism DebugLogger save the log file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, exception, prism, error-logging

I am using the Prism DebugLogger in my catch block as follows:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
   new DebugLogger().Log(e.Message, Category.Exception, Priority.High);
}
```

I am not sure if this is the complete implementation and if it is, does the logger save the log file somewhere automatically by default(like in the project's debug folder) or whether i have to save it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default implementation provided by the Prism.Core has to be cross platform friendly. You will only see the output from the DebugLogger in your Application Output from your IDE. If you look at the [code](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Logging/DebugLogger.cs#L24), you'll notice it's just using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`. If you want something more advanced you'll need to provide your own implementation.